# Programmatically extract files from dd image in C

Tags: c, linux, image, file, extract

I have a few dd images and I wanted to know the best way of extracting files out of these using C.  The images are of mixed file systems (fat32, ntfs, ext2/3) and the host machine doing the extraction would be an Ubuntu box, so you can assume kernel headers and GNU C library, etc.

Natively would be best, but external libraries that do the job would also be fine.  A link to an example would be perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a significant effort.  You'd have to essentially reimplement filesystem drivers for NTFS, FAT, and EXT2.  I've done this for FAT and NTFS, but it took more than two years, though much of that was reverse engineering NTFS.

Consider using the [`file mount`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/intrepid/man8/mount.8.html) option of the mount command so you can use the Ubuntu filesystem drivers and not reinvent the significantly large wheel.  Then you can peruse the mounted filesystems.

Comment: You can't link against Linux's file system modules using kernel headers and accomplish the same task?

Comment: You could, but only with heavy accommodation for all the dependencies on the kernel.  If it's a permissions issue of not wanting to allow the user to actually mount file systems, you'd probably have an easier time doing the extraction in the context of an entire linux kernel in userpace rather than pieces of one - ie, user mode linux.  Obviously once you start using bits of the kernel, there's no licensing difference between using bits of it and using the whole thing.

Comment: There is no issue with licensing, this is mostly out of curiosity and to try to do something new with my programming experience.  I haven't done file system level coding before so I figured this would be a great way to learn how Linux handles them

Answer (score 2):

Why programatically with C?

`sudo mount -o loop,offset=[offset] -t auto [where] [what]`

#### Where

**offset** is the offset in bytes from the beginning of the disk, in bytes

**where** is where on the current filesystem to mount the image

**what** is the disk image you're mounting

Comment: The number one reason is curiosity :).  I am aware of many alternative ways to do this.

Comment: Why C? Because. See `man 2 mount`, and for loop devices, there are enough simple examples floating around (since there ain't a manpage for that).

Comment: @user562374: Read closer.  Why **programatically** with C was the question.  This is reinventing a gigantic item for no reason other than curiosity, which is ok.

Comment: Thank you for the man 2 mount command.. I haven't found a single example around for loop devices though, care to share one of them?

Answer (score 1):

Look at [The Sleuth Kit](http://www.sleuthkit.org/sleuthkit/desc.php), which should work with all of the file system types you listed:

> The original part of Sleuth Kit is a C library and collection of command line file and volume system forensic analysis tools. The file system tools allow you to examine file systems of a suspect computer in a non-intrusive fashion. Because the tools do not rely on the operating system to process the file systems, deleted and hidden content is shown. It runs on Windows and Unix platforms.

The Sleuth Kit's existing toolset is a great place to start if you're looking for sample code to work from.

Answer (score 0):

Check out:

- [ext2fuse](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2fuse/) or [fuse-ext2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fuse-ext2/) projects, they contain some ext2/ext3 implementations on user space using [FUSE](http://fuse.sf.net).
- [ntfs-3g](http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-download/), an NTFS implementation also using FUSE.
- [FUSE](http://fuse.sf.net) itself, as there are lots of [filesystem implementations](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/fuse/index.php?title=FileSystems) on top of it.